# Laravel Database Query Not Returning Data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

The Query

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
$group_users = GroupUser::where('user_id', $user_id);
return view('groups.index', ['group_users' => $group_users]);
```

My Query has no errors

I need to list all rows from the group_users table with the the user ID that is equal to the

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
```

I am including the model with

```
use App\GroupUser;
```

And my table I am retrieving the data from has the following fields,

```
- group_id
- user_id
- user_role
```

And if I echo or print the

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
```

I get the correct user id. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GroupUser::where` does not execute a query. To get results add `get()` chaining method:

```
$group_users = GroupUser::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!!!! :D  I will accept answer as soon as it lets me :D

Answer (score 0):

GroupUser::where('user_id', $user_id) just return a builder.If you want return data you can fix :

$group_users = GroupUser::where('user_id', $user_id)->first(); to return first data

or

$group_users = GroupUser::where('user_id', $user_id)->get(); to return all data of table GroupUser